# driver.title not working in selenium webdriver with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is button which on clicking navigates to facebook login page and I want to confirm it navigates properly using `selenium`. However on button click the facebook login opens in a new tab but the `driver.title` returns the title of previous tab (where the button is present).

```
def test_01_facebook(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-facebook-square']").click()
        title = self.driver.title
        self.assertTrue("Facebook" == self.driver.title) 
        print (title)
```

Alternatively I could compare the url using `driver.current_url` but the issue is the new tab url has a lengthy string after `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?`.

Comment: Please explain how this question relates to the tag "coded-ui-tests" or if it does not then please remove the tag.

Comment: I believe coded-ui-tests tag is used for automated tests that drive applications through its user interface for functional testing of the UI controls. The above code is an automated script to to test the functionality of button, so I think it relates. Please do correct me if i'm wrong. @AdrianHHH

Comment: Coded UI Tests are a specific type of test supported by and implemented with Visual Studio. It is not a generic style of UI testing. Hover the mouse over the tag in the question or view this page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coded-ui-tests/info

Comment: I'm new to this UI testing and I mistook `coded-ui-tests` for automated ui testing turns out it is a different tool like selenium used for UI testing. Thanks @AdrianHHH for the correction.

Comment: @Atul Consider evaluating all the answer's you receive against your question and provide a feedback to the answer contributors. It takes some serious efforts to construct canonical answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the facebook is opened in a new tab, so you need switch to the new tab first, please try below code:

```
 self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-facebook-square']").click()
 windowHandle = self.driver.window_handles
 for windowId in self.driver.window_handles:
      if not windowId==windowHandle
          self.driver.switch_to.window(windowId);

 title = self.driver.title
 self.assertTrue("Facebook" == self.driver.title) 
 print (title)
```

Comment: Yep that was the issue. `self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)`  was not working for me. But I found this one to be working `self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

If LogIn page opens in new tab, you should wait for new tab and switch to it to check title:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def test_01_facebook(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-facebook-square']").click()
    current = self.driver.current_window_handle
    wait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.new_window_is_opened(self.driver.window_handles))
    self.driver.switch_to.window([w for w in self.driver.window_handles if w != current][0])
    title = self.driver.title
    self.assertTrue("Facebook" == self.driver.title) 
    print (title)
```

You might also switch back to main window using

```
self.driver.switch_to.window(current)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *Page Title* from the newly opened *TAB* i.e. **Facebook – log in or sign up** you need to:

- Switch the **focus** to the newly opened *TAB* inducing *WebDriverWait*
- You need to induce *WebDriverWait* again for the *Page Title* to render.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  def test_01_facebook(self):
      windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
      self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-facebook-square']").click()
      WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
      windows_after = driver.window_handles
      new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
      driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
      WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("log in"))
      self.assert "Python" in driver.title
      print (title)
  ```